# too many wrong region proposals with Region Proposal Network

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

I am trying to implement the feature pyramid networks for object detection (basically replace a single feature in faster r cnn to be pyramid features) with gland dataset. And now I want to make sure the RPN which is the first state of Faster-RCNN work, so I only trained the RPN. I trained 40001 iterations, initial lr is 0.001, backbone is ResNet_V2_50. But I got several problems:

1. I found out the weight basically is not updated after 5000 iterations, and the gradients are really close to zero. [wired weight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzZCB.jpg)
   I have tried to use a lower lr, and the epsilon I use in the tf.train.AdamOptimizer is 0.0001. Still the weight seems not updated.
2. As for the prediction, I feel the bounding box prediction is quite ok (green are the ground truth, red are the predicted box, these predicted boxes are selected if the anchors has a overlapping ratio larger than 0.7 with the ground truth bounding box), [predicted bounding box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTnnk.png), so it means at least the bounding box regression loss can make the prediction close to the ground truth. But as for the rpn_cls_loss, it classify too many wrong proposals to be object[wrong proposals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVlVg.png). I have consider the class imbalance problem(in gland cell dataset, average number of positive anchors is only 20 per image, only 85 training images), so I random choose 128 positive anchor and 128 negative anchors (if the positive anchor smaller than 128, I random_shuffle the index so one positive anchor will appear several times), but still it doesn't work. One thing I don't understand is that when we calculate the loss, we only consider a minibatch, but at the same time, we classify all the anchors that we generated to be a object or non-object, so what about those anchors which are not contributing to the loss? Can the network also make correct decision for those anchors?

This is the code for extracting pyramid feature map:

```
P5 = conv_layer_obj(conv5_3,"fpn_c5p5",[1,256], training_state = training_state, activation_func = None, bias_state = True, padding = 'valid')
P4_ = conv_layer_obj(conv4_3, "fpn_c4p4", [1,256], training_state = training_state, activation_func = None, bias_state = True, padding = 'valid')
P3_ = conv_layer_obj(conv3_3, "fpn_c3p3", [1,256], training_state = training_state, activation_func = None, bias_state = True, padding = 'valid')
P2_ = conv_layer_obj(conv2_2, "fpn_c2p2", [1,256], training_state = training_state, activation_func = None, bias_state = True, padding = 'valid')
#P4 = tf.add(tf.image.resize_bilinear(P5,[P4_.shape.as_list()[1],P4_.shape.as_list()[1]]),P4_)
P4 = tf.add(utils.nearest_neighbor_upsampling(P5, scale = 2), P4_)  
P3 = tf.add(utils.nearest_neighbor_upsampling(P4, scale = 2),P3_)
P2 = tf.add(utils.nearest_neighbor_upsampling(P3, scale = 2),P2_)

P5 = conv_layer_obj(P5,"fpn_p5", [3,256], training_state = training_state, activation_func = None, bias_state = True)

P4 = conv_layer_obj(P4,"fpn_p4", [3,256], training_state = training_state, activation_func = None, bias_state = True)    
P3 = conv_layer_obj(P3,"fpn_p3", [3,256], training_state = training_state, activation_func = None, bias_state = True)

P2 = conv_layer_obj(P2,"fpn_p2", [3,256], training_state = training_state, activation_func = None, bias_state = True)
#P6 is used for the 5th anchor scale in RPN, generated by subsampling from P5 by strid 2. The shape should be
#as same as P4
P6 = tf.nn.max_pool(P5,[1,2,2,1],strides = [1,2,2,1], padding = 'VALID', name = "fpn_p6")
```

This is the code for rpn

```
anchors = utils.generate_pyramid_anchors(config.RPN_ANCHOR_SCALES, config.RPN_ANCHOR_RATIOS, config.BACKBONE_SHAPES,
                                         config.BACKBONE_STRIDES, config.RPN_ANCHOR_STRIDE)
#Basically, in this step, the anchors that we generated is all the possible anchors in the image. The RPN_ANCHOR_SCALES is
#32,64,128,256,512 which means there are 5 level, and the anchors returned is arranged in this order. The number mean if
#The RPN_ANCHOR_RATIOS is 1, then the bounding box will include 32*32 pixels for the first level of scale. Here it's like
#a selective research, we list all the possible anchors.

layer_outputs = [] #list of lists
index = 0
#rpn_graph(feature_map, anchor_per_location, anchor_stride, reuse_state, training_state):
for index, single_feature in enumerate(rpn_feature_maps): 
    if (index == 0):
        layer_outputs.append(rpn_graph(single_feature, len(config.RPN_ANCHOR_RATIOS), config.RPN_ANCHOR_STRIDE,
                                       reuse_state = False, training_state = training_state))
    else:
        layer_outputs.append(rpn_graph(single_feature, len(config.RPN_ANCHOR_RATIOS), config.RPN_ANCHOR_STRIDE,
                                       reuse_state = True, training_state = training_state))
#Then concatenate the layer_outputs from [[a1,b1,c1],[a2,b2,c2]] to [[a1,a2],[b1,b2],[c1,c2]]
output_names = ["rpn_class_logits","rpn_class","rpn_bbox"]
outputs = list(zip(*layer_outputs))
output_concate = []
for o, n in zip(outputs, output_names):
    output_concate.append(tf.concat(list(o),axis=1,name = n))

rpn_class_logits, rpn_class_prob, rpn_bbox = output_concate

#Then we need to filter out those bounding boxes that are not satisfied the criterion. 
proposal_count =  tf.cond(training_state,
                          lambda: config.POST_NMS_ROIS_TRAINING,
                          lambda: config.POST_NMS_ROIS_INFERENCE)

#This is for proposing the #Number of bounding box that kind of satisfy the criterion, we assume that there are almost 2000
#boxes in each image.
proposallayer = ProposalLayer(proposal_count, config.RPN_NMS_THRESHOLD,anchors = anchors,config = config)
rpn_rois = proposallayer.call([rpn_class_prob, rpn_bbox])
```

rpn_graph is:

```
def rpn_graph(feature_map, anchor_per_location, anchor_stride, reuse_state, training_state):
"""This function is for building up the region proposal graph

Args:
feature_map: The pyramide feature maps. They have different height, width, but same batch size, and Num_of_Channel. 
anchor_per_location: The number of anchors for per pixel in the feature map
anchor_stride: Controls the density of the anchor, most of time we set it to be 1. In our case, we will set it to be 1.
                anchor_stride is only a int number
training_state: since the training process for rpn and fast rcnn are different, so that the training state is a dynamic variable

Returns:
rpn_class_logits. Shape [Batch_Size, Num_of_Anchors, 2]
rpn_class_prob. Shape [Batch_Size, Num_of_Anchors, 2]
rpn_bbox. Shape [Batch_Size, Num_of_Anchors, 4] (dx,dy,log(dw),log(dh))
"""

#Frist, build the shared feature maps, this is used for the rpn_class_logit, as same as rpn_bbox 
#conv_layer_obj(bottom, name, shape, stride, bias_state, relu_state, padding):
#conv_layer_obj(bottom, name, shape, training_state, strides = (1,1), activation_func = tf.nn.relu, padding='same', dilation_rate = (1,1), bias_state = True, reuse_state = False):
shared = conv_layer_obj(feature_map,'rpn_conv_shared',shape = [3,512],strides = anchor_stride, bias_state = True, 
                        activation_func = tf.nn.relu, padding = 'same', reuse_state = reuse_state, training_state = training_state)

#Then, let's do the rpn_class_logit, the output shape for the classifier should be [anchor_per_location*2]
#2 is because either it is a object or it is the background!!!
x = conv_layer_obj(shared,'rpn_class_classifier',shape = [1,anchor_per_location*2], strides = (1,1), bias_state = True,
                   activation_func = None, padding = 'same', reuse_state = reuse_state, training_state = training_state)
rpn_class_logit = tf.reshape(x,[x.shape.as_list()[0],-1,2])
rpn_class_prob = tf.nn.softmax(rpn_class_logit)

#Then, let's do the bounding box refinement. The output shape for the classifier should be [anchor_per_location*4]
#4 is because they are [ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax]
x = conv_layer_obj(shared,'rpn_box_classifier',shape = (1,anchor_per_location*4), strides = (1,1), bias_state = True,
                   activation_func = None, padding = 'same', reuse_state = reuse_state, training_state = training_state)
rpn_bbox = tf.reshape(x,[x.shape.as_list()[0],-1,4])

return [rpn_class_logit,rpn_class_prob,rpn_bbox]
```

I would really appreciate your help, thanksss a lottt in advance!

Comment: I figured it out. I am supposed to have lots of bounding boxes after RPN, as long as there are enough bounding boxes covering the objects, because for those bounding box which only cover the background will probability filtered out by the second faster rcnn stage. And also the unique probability is also solved by changing the std for initialized kernel weight from 0,1 to 0.01 and had a L2 regu term.